# Cant upload to arduino with Arduino IDE in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, serial-port, arduino

Hey guys my computer runs Ubuntu 22.04.

And the Arduino IDE doesn't show any serial ports when a board is connected.

This is what it shows when the board is disconnected:
[image]

And this is what it shows when the board is connected:
[image]


As you can see the board does not get detected by the IDE. But when I run `lsusb` in the terminal, I can see the device:
[image]


So the device does get detected by the computer but not by the IDE.
I have also tried running 
 `./arduino-linux-setup.sh $USER`, which adds the user to the dialout, tty, uucp, and plugdev groups, but that didn't work.

Please suggest a method to resolve this problem. Also, please feel free to ask for other additional information.


Thank you.

Comment: did you log out and back in after adding yourself to those groups?

Comment: also I assume you're using an Arduino Nano... otherwise you should change the "board" property

Comment: Yes, I did restart my computer. And yes I am using an Arduino Nano but I have also tried it with my esp32, still got the same results